# Object does not accept method

Tags: ms-access, excel, field, recordset, vba

I'm experiencing a problem with my VBA application.
I need to define a Recordset and enter the result of a certain field, line by line, into an Excel Worksheet.
The problem is, when I do this

```
With appXLS.Worksheets("Resultado Geral")
    For intPosition = LBound(Arr) To (UBound(Arr) - 1)
        teste = Arr(intPosition, 0) & "_Status"
        .Cells(i, 6) = MyRecBase.Fields(teste)
    Next
End With
```

It displays the problem (Error '438') and marks the ".Cells" line. But the biggest problem is that I use the same method a few lines before.

Please, help me. I would appreciate.

Thanks in advance

Comment: in your line `.Cells(i, 6) = MyRecBase.Fields(teste)` what is "i" and how is it calculated?

Comment: Man, I'm feeling awkward and dumb. I forgot the i increment. Thanks for the light.

Comment: @i_saw_drones I'd suggest that you post again your comment as a proper post (to be checked as answer) and 'close' the topic. This has been suggested here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77900/marking-comment-as-an-answer

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso Good point, thanks for highlighting that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the line in your code:

```
.Cells(i, 6) = MyRecBase.Fields(teste)
```

since it is not evident what `i` is and how it is calculated based on your loop.

Comment: Man, sorry. I needed to uncheck your answer, as this don't work out anymore. I don't know why, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Patrick Villela Could you perhaps update your question with the new issue if it's related (otherwise ask a new question)?

Comment: Reaccepted your answer. I didn't happen to know that I need to set de recordset as nothing before using it again. Thanks for the support.